# Set format for decimal number

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am validating certain input by using `RegEx` in `jQuery` which is working as expected. I want to add an addition where it adds 0 prior to decimal point if user don't add it.

For example,

```
.50 to 0.50
-.50 to -0.50
```

How to do that?

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnval').click(function() {
    var floatRegex = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]+([\,|\.]{0,1}[0-9]{2}){0,1}$/);
    var currentSetTextBoxValue = $('#txtval').val();
    //alert(currentSetTextBoxValue);
    var validateInput = floatRegex.test(currentSetTextBoxValue);
    alert(validateInput);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtval" />
<input type="button" value="Get textbox Value" id="btnval" />
```

Comment: That's the normal format that `toFixed(2)` produces.

Comment: FYI, `{0,1}` can be simplified to `?`, which means that something is optional.

Comment: Removed references to jquery as jquery is only used for the click event/val and is not pertinent to the question.

Comment: I put in Barmars change. https://jsfiddle.net/str59woa/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `[0-9]+` to `[0-9]*`, so that it allows zero digits instead of requireing at least one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnval').click(function() {
    var floatRegex = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]*([\,|\.]{0,1}[0-9]{2}){0,1}$/);
    var currentSetTextBoxValue = $('#txtval').val();
    //alert(currentSetTextBoxValue);
    var validateInput = floatRegex.test(currentSetTextBoxValue);
    alert(validateInput);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtval" />
<input type="button" value="Get textbox Value" id="btnval" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the value like this if you need to convert it later:

```
if(currentSetTextBoxValue.indexOf('.') === 0){
    currentSetTextBoxValue = '0' + currentSetTextBoxValue;
}
if(currentSetTextBoxValue.indexOf('.') === 1 && currentSetTextBoxValue.indexOf('-') === 0){
    currentSetTextBoxValue = '-0.' + currentSetTextBoxValue.split('.')[1];
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/str59woa/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the input using regex! This regex looks for . or -. at the beginning of the string and it will replace it by 0. or -0. depending on what it found, if it does not match the string will be the same.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnval').click(function() {
    var floatRegex = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]+([\,|\.]{0,1}[0-9]{2}){0,1}$/);
    var currentSetTextBoxValue = $('#txtval').val().replace(/^(\-)?\./, "$10.");
    //alert(currentSetTextBoxValue);
    var validateInput = floatRegex.test(currentSetTextBoxValue);
    alert(validateInput);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtval" />
<input type="button" value="Get textbox Value" id="btnval" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/punsm9o0/1/